# How can i select particular currency from api in python?

Tags: python, list, api, python-requests, currency

I want to select TRY currency from an api. When i print that request text, it shows dozens of currencies. How can i select only one currency (TRY)?

Code is below. This code gives the currency list.

```
import pandas as pd
from datetime import datetime
 
 
rsp = requests.get("https://openexchangerates.org/api/latest.json?app_id=KEY").json()
 
print(rsp)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import pandas as pd
import requests
from datetime import datetime
 
 
rsp = requests.get("https://openexchangerates.org/api/latest.json?app_id=c92e9bfec2584ff0848965f86681ec37").json()
 
print(rsp["rates"]["TRY"])
```

Answer (score 0):

You can either use square brackets or `.get()` to access a key of the result you got from the api (as a dictionary)

```
import requests
rsp = requests.get("https://openexchangerates.org/api/latest.json?app_id=c92e9bfec2584ff0848965f86681ec37").json()
```

In your case TRY is listed inside rates. You can access it like this:

```
rsp.get("rates").get("TRY")
```